# how to generate a list of 3-digit numbers?

Tags: python, math, random, numbers, probability

How can I generate a list of 3-digit numbers for which the sum of their digits equal 17?

For example assuming number `XYZ`, we would have `X+Y+Z=17`

This is how far I got:

```
numbers = list(range(1, 1000))
```

Comment: How can the sum of three, 3-digit positive numbers be 17?

Comment: 001, 002, 003, 004. etc.

Comment: like 197 and 188 and....

Comment: @AmmarMohammed That is the sum of the digits; not the sum of the numbers as you say in the question.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The question is clear enough. I don't know why you think it's ambiguous.

Comment: What does this have to do with "random" and "probability"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want the sum of the **digits** to be 17 and not the sum of the **numbers** as the *"but I want the first number + the second number + the third number = 17 ?"* implies.

So, take a look at this:

```
result = [x for x in range(100, 1000) if sum(int(y) for y in str(x))==17]
print(result)  # [179, 188, 197, 269, ..., 962, 971, 980]
```

Comment: You are missing stuff like `098`

Comment: @Bentaye That is not a 3-digit number. Because if it was, it would also be an n-digit number at the same time by adding appropriate padding. And that cannot be.

Comment: In my opinion `098` can be reduced to `98`, which is a 2-digits number. You're getting badly oriented due to OP's wrong start (`numbers = list(range(1, 1000))`).

Answer (score 1):

You can first generate a list of numbers that matches your condition like,

```
test_list = [value for value in range(100, 1000, 1) if sum(int(a) for a in str(value)) is 17]
```

So to make this a random list, you can use `random` package.

```
random.shuffle(test_list)
```

So `test_list` wil be a completely random list with all the possible three digit numbers in it. So this could be the fastest way to generate a random list matching your condition. ([shuffle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215737/how-python-random-shuffle-works))

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**
This method will be random and you can have duplicates. If you want an exhaustive list of unique numbers, it will not work, and you might prefer **Ev. Kounis'** solution.

Here we go, pick 2 digits which sum is between 8 and 17, then calculate the required 3rd one to add up to 17.

The sum of the first 2 digits needs to be:

- 8 or more because you can have 9 max for the last digit
- 17 or less because you can't have negative numbers for the last digit

This way:

```
import random 

def getAnotherNumber():
    d1 = 0
    d2 = 0
    while 17 < d1 + d2 or  d1 + d2 < 8:
        d1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
        d2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
    d3 = 17-d1-d2
    return  100*d1 + 10* d2 + d3

# Make a list of 10 numbers    
list = [getAnotherNumber() for x in range(10)]

print(list)
```

outputs something like this:

```
[773, 746, 980, 179, 269, 179, 755, 485, 755, 476]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more comment, and/or if what I've done is not what you asked (somehow), tell me. :)

```
#   All numbers having 3 digits.
numbers = [x for x in range(100, 1000)]

newList = []
for number in numbers:
    #   Integer to string.
    str_number = str(number)

    #   Separating digits using strings, and casting result to int.
    real_a = int(str_number[0])
    real_b = int(str_number[1])
    real_c = int(str_number[2])

    # Summing, and checking result.
    digitsSum = real_a + real_b + real_c
    if digitsSum == 17:
        newList.append(number)

print newList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## Sum of digits of individual number
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ## Declare a list
    alist = list()

    ## Iterate from 100 - 1000
    for x in range(100,1000):
        tmp = sum_digits(x)

        ## Add to list once its sum is equal to 17
        if tmp ==  17:
            alist.append(x)

    print alist
```