# how to generate a list of 3-digit numbers the sum of their digits equal 17?

Tags: python

How can I generate a list of 3-digit numbers for which the sum of their digits equal 17?
for example: **0**98, 197, 188, etc..

Comment: Okay. What have *you* tried?

Comment: I want like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769342/how-to-generate-a-list-of-3-digit-numbers/48769540#48769540 but with the numbers that begins with 0 .

Comment: have you actually tried to code this yourself to see what is possible

Comment: Why don't you give it a try yourself first and come back if you're stuck someplace (along with all your codes).

Comment: Well, you only want numbers from 10 to 100 then. It should be easy to change the answer in the question you have linked accordingly

Comment: so you already have an answer you just don't like it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution with list comprehension

```
[(a,b,c) for a in range(10) for b in range(10) for c in range(10) if a+b+c ==17]
```

Then just convert this to strings or whatever you want.

Comment: At least make it somewhat efficient and calculate `c`: `[(a, b, 17 - a - b) for a in range(10) for b in range(10) if 0 <= 17 - a - b < 10]`. This is about 8 times faster in this case.